# choosing an Engineering degree for embedded systems and IoT

Tags: embedded

I am applying for university right now and I am wondering which engineering degree is better for working on embedded systems and IOT: "Computer engineering" vs "electronics and communication engineering" also a specefic university offers "computer and communication engineering" I know that having any of those I can get into IoT but which would be better for the field?

if you can spare some more time here are the sourses for each in one of the universities I am looking at, the rest aren't that different:
http://www.aast.edu/en/colleges/coe/dept/programtemp.php?menutab=52&program_id=5&unit_id=66
http://www.aast.edu/en/colleges/coe/dept/programtemp.php?menutab=51&program_id=51&unit_id=65

Comment: Really doesn't matter. They both are going to teach you math.

Comment: Instead of asking **others** what you should do, why not start from **your own interests**. Also IoT is a hype at this moment, it could have become irrelevant by the time you have finished your studies. Good engineers never study to do something specific like IoT, they follow their **interests** and try to become **good** in that subject. Then a job will often follow without much effort.

Comment: Ditto. You know, most of us here have finished their degrees long before the abbreviation IoT have appeared... Even "Embedded" wasn't that widespread. It was just "Electrical Engineering".

Comment: @EugeneSh. Or "physics"!

Comment: @DirkBruere Is it about the first or second comment?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The one preceding mine

Comment: @DirkBruere Well.. that's a bit of extreme :) Not many of EEs have taken this path, I believe.

Comment: Get theee a Raspberry PI and tinker with it. Also get a white board protoboard, and build a common-emitter amplifier ---- multistage preferred, with emitter-bypassed biasing. Use +6v or +9v battery as (safe) power. Use earphones to listen to the amplifier. Connect a loudspeaker to the input, and tap or scratch on the speaker diagram, as your test input. Get started.

Answer (score 1):

As an employer, I usually find that the guys with computer in their specialization are often not embedded but more upper-level.  More important is to get involved in projects or get an internship that demonstrates your ability to apply these skills.

Answer (score 0):

Designing/Making IoT devices in the millions will be done by a few engineers working for big companies. They will be used by a far larger array of engineers working at a much higher level eg systems, database, webserver etc. Choose the level you wish to work at.